# perform an animation from the current position of the element at 10px on the right

Tags: css

I'm new to this topic of animations. Basically I want to move a div `.son` in your `hover` property. I would like this animation to start from its `current position` at `10px` on the `right`. I am normally able to perform this animation by defining an initial position for "left" and an ending for "left" but in this case I want it to take the initial position in which it is and thus move 10px to the right.

```
<div class="father">
  <div class="son">
  </div>
</div>

.father{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.son{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;

}

.son:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-animation: fadein_1 0.2s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein_1 {
    from { opacity: 1;left:auto;z-index:2;  }
    to { opacity: 0; left:10px;z-index:3; }
}
```

this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ze9vdLa3/it?

thanks

Comment: Your demo doesnt exist plus you should use transform: translateX and not left its better for the performance

Comment: @JoeKoker sounds interesting. can you post your answer please? I still do not understand how to define the initial position.

Comment: @JoeKoker from:??? to: translateX...

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, check this :
https://jsfiddle.net/95agyjuo/

```
jQuery('.son').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery(this).animate({ 
    left : "+=10"
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the desired animation using the CSS [translateX()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) function. As @Joe Koker stated, this is more performant than animating the `left` property.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein_1 {
    from { 
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px); //start from initial position
        z-index:2;
    }
    to { 
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(10px); //move 10px
        z-index:3;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works .. but .. why the animation does not look smooth?

Comment: Choppy animations can be caused by a number of factors, and without looking at your whole codebase I can't diagnose a specific issue. You could try adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to both your `from` and `to` blocks, which won't animate anything but will trigger GPU accelerated rendering and *may* give you smoother FPS. More on that here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/ . To troubleshoot it properly though, open up the Performance tab in your browser's devtools and see what's causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but if what you want is to animate an element to the right, it's easy. You almost had it.

Some things:

- It's not possible to animate from `auto`, so I had to change `left:auto` -> `left: 0;` (`from { opacity: 1;left:0;z-index:2;  }`)
- `-webkit-` isn't necessary
- It's not possible to animate z-index either

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqdn6xLg/1/

Though for this use case, I would recommend using the `transition` property instead, as its simpler. Check out the difference here: https://jsfiddle.net/L04xhgpr/

Note that `transform: translateX()` performs better, as others have already said :)